# Add DIN B4 format to scan formats

Tags: scanner, scanning, multi-function-printer, document-scanning

we are using Kyocera 4054ci printers in our office and one department regularly scans files in the DIN B4 format, which is not available in the formats provided by Kyocera.

Is it possible to manually add that format or any other format to the scan options.

Thank you in advance